# Null reference exception when setting Masterpage label text in content page visual basic asp.net

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am trying to set label text which is in my navbar.  This navbar is in my masterpage and I am using Master.nameoflabel to try and set the label's text in my content page.  When I try and set the text however I get a null reference exception because my label is returning nothing which I cannot figure out.  These are the labels I am trying to set in my content page :

```
                    <div class="leftPanel">
                        <%-- DXCOMMENT: Configure the left panel's ASPxNavBar --%>
                        <dx:ASPxNavBar ID="ASPxNavBar1" runat="server" AutoCollapse="false" EnableAnimation="True" Theme="Default">

                            <ItemStyle Wrap="True"></ItemStyle>

                            <Border BorderWidth="0px" />
                            <Paddings Padding="0px" />
                            <Groups>
                                <dx:NavBarGroup Text="Totals" Expanded="True">
                                    <Items>
                                        <dx:NavBarItem>
                                            <Template>
                                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="potentialDeadStocklbl" runat="server" Text="test123"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                                                        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="potentialMTLDeadStocklbl" runat="server" Text="test"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                                                        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="potentialWIPDeadStocklbl" runat="server" Text="test"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                                                        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="toolingDeadStocklbl" runat="server" Text="test"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                                                        <dx:ASPxLabel ID="estimatedDeadStockTotallbl" runat="server" Text="test"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                            </Template>
                                        </dx:NavBarItem>
                                    </Items>
                                </dx:NavBarGroup>
                            </Groups>

                        </dx:ASPxNavBar>
                    </div>
```

In this masterpage's code behind I am setting the text in properties as such:

```
Public Property FGDeadStock As String
    Get
        Return potentialDeadStocklbl.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        potentialDeadStocklbl.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property MTLDeadStock As String
    Get
        Return potentialMTLDeadStocklbl.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        potentialMTLDeadStocklbl.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property WIPDeadStock As String
    Get
        Return potentialWIPDeadStocklbl.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        potentialWIPDeadStocklbl.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property ToolingDeadStock As String
    Get
        Return toolingDeadStocklbl.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        toolingDeadStocklbl.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property EstimatedDeadStockTotal As String
    Get
        Return estimatedDeadStockTotallbl.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        estimatedDeadStockTotallbl.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Then in my content page I am trying to set the text:

```
Master.FGDeadStock = "Test"
Master.MTLDeadStock = "Test1"
Master.WIPDeadStock = "Test2"
Master.ToolingDeadStock = "Test3"
Master.EstimatedDeadStockTotal = "Test4"
```

I did a very similar thing in a different page and it works fine on the other page, I am not sure why this isn't working maybe there is something small I'm not noticing, thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Have you tried casting the Master back to MyMasterPage (the name of your master page).  I am a c# guy, but I know that Master tends to be generic, and that you can cast it to the actual named master page class and get type defined access to all the public methods and properties.

Comment: I have the masterpage said by using this code so that it can reference the properties. <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Phaseout/Main.master" %>

Comment: From a c# view, Master.FGDeadStock would not work.  You would need to do ((Main)Master).FGDeadStock.  The casting is required to make generic Master into specific Main: Master in order to get at the specific properties.